# ASP.NET - Unable to insert data into database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, ado.net

I know that the connection string is not the problem because I can read data from the database fine but I cannot figure out why I cannot insert data into the database.

**.aspx file**

```
<div class="column one-second">
  <asp:TextBox placeholder="Your name" type="text" name="name" id="namelbl" size="40" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>

<div class="column one-second">
  <asp:TextBox placeholder="location" type="text" name="location" id="LocationLbl" size="40" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="column one">
  <asp:TextBox placeholder="Body" type="text" name="text" id="TextLBL" size="40" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="column one">
  <asp:FileUpload id="FileUpload1" runat="server"> </asp:FileUpload>

  <asp:Label ID="lblmessage" runat="server" />
</div>
<div class="column one">
  <asp:Button id="submit" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="submit_Click"> </asp:Button>
</div>
```

**C# function**

```cs
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("BUTTON CLICKED");
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO blo(Title, post, location) VALUES (@Title, @post, @location)";
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;

            string title = namelbl.Text;
            Console.WriteLine(title);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Title", title);
            string post = TextLBL.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("post", post);
            string location = LocationLbl.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("location", location);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?  Should "INSERT INTO blo" be "INSERT INTO blog"?

Answer (score 2):

Your query was not able to work as you mistype the parameter name in your `.AddWithValue()`.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Title", title);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("post", post);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("location", location);
```

The correct way should be:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", title);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@post", post);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", location);
```

---

### RECOMMENDATIONS

1. It is recommended not to use `.AddWithValue()` as the concern mentioned in this [article](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Please ensure that you need to pass the value with **exact datatype and length** that matches the respective table column in the `SqlParameter`.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param", <<MySqlDbType>>, <<Length>>).Value = value;
```

2. As you apply using block for `MySqlConnection`, `MySqlCommand`, you don't have to manually call `con.Close()` as these IDisposable objects will dispose the resources & connection automatically as mentioned in this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement#remarks).
3. *(Optional)* Add `try catch` block and get value from `ExecuteNonQuery()` for verifying the record is inserted into the database and exception handling.

- Exception handling will be useful in debugging and handling the exception hit during the execution. At the same time, you can provide a meaningful error message to notify the users.
- [ExecuteNonQuery()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery?view=netframework-4.8) able to return the value indicate

> The number of rows affected.

- Hence, this will also be useful to return a useful message to notify whether the record is successfully inserted/updated into the database or not.

In the end, your code should be:

```
try
{
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
    {
        string query = "INSERT INTO blo(Title, post, location) VALUES (@Title, @Post, @Location)";
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;

            string title = namelbl.Text;
            Console.WriteLine(title);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", title);
        
            string post = TextLBL.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Post", post);

            string location = LocationLbl.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", location);
        
            con.Open();
            var recordAffected = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (recordAffected > 0)
            {
                // Record successfully inserted case
            }
            else
            {
                // Record fail inserted case
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handling exception
}
```

**Edited**:
Much appreciated and credited to the comment provided by @BradleyGrainger, I had 'strikethrough' recommendation 1 as the concerns mentioned in [Can We Stop Using .AddWithValue()](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) are handled by MySql.

[Start Using AddWithValue](https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/using-addwithvalue/)

> The primary reason that AddWithValue is OK to use is that MySQL’s text protocol is not typed in a way that matters for client-side type inference.

Comment: It's completely fine to use `AddWithValue` for MySQL: https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/using-addwithvalue/. In fact, you should avoid use `SqlDbType` with MySqlConnector; those are types for `SqlClient` (MS SQL Server).

Comment: Hi @BradleyGrainger, thanks for the suggestion and the article. I will update the solution based on the article. Thanks a lot again.